# C# code generation to edit an existing class

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn

I have a static class Items.cs, and I want to add persistent content to this class using code generation:

```
public static class Items
{
    public static List<Item> ItemList = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Name1"
        },
        new Item
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Name2"
        }
    };
}
```

Ideally, I would like to create a new Item instance from a console app, add it to ItemList, and then save the cs file with the updated list. I tried to read a bit about Roslyn and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis but couldn't find a very simple way to do it. Do you know of anything that can help to write this scenario in an elegant simple way?

Comment: There is T4 TextTemplate project item. It can be used to generate source code. But what is the data source for code generation?

Comment: I want someone to run a console app, enter id and name, and then those will be added as a new item to the list and saved to the cs file (the real scenario is to support automatic tests based on data entered from console application, but just gave a simple example here to explain the need)

Answer (score 1):

See [Introducing C# Source Generators (Microsoft DevBlogs)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/)

Comment: helpful info about source generators: https://channel9.msdn.com/events/dotnetConf/2020/C-Source-Generators-Write-Code-that-Writes-Code?term=source%20generators&lang-en=true

Answer (score 0):

You can use [T4 Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019) to automatically generate persistent code.